# apt-get: Unmet Dependencies and Conflicting (?) Output on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, source-packages

I'm trying to [install common-lisp-jupyter](https://yitzchak.github.io/common-lisp-jupyter/install.html) on Ubuntu 21.10, but Ubuntu won’t install one of the required libraries, namely `zeromq`.

When I tried to install `zeromq` using the `libczmq-dev` package, `apt-get` reported that there are two unmet dependencies, but `apt-get` also says that both the missing (?) packages are installed and up to date.

More specifically, when I try this:

`sudo apt-get install libczmq-dev`

I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsodium-dev : Depends: libsodium23 (= 1.0.18-1build1) but 1.0.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.12+dfsg-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.9.13+dfsg-0+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
```

But `libsodium23` and `libxml2` are both installed and up to date. I tried to call `apt-get` using the `-f` option and to install `libczmq-dev` using `aptitude`, but nothing worked. The output from `aptitude` says that the package "is not installable," but gives no clues as to why.

Even more baffling is that when I try:

`aptitude install libsodium23`

It returns

`libsodium23 is already installed at the requested version (1.0.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)`.

Doesn't this conflict with the output from `apt-get`?

The system is running on a Dell desktop machine. It was recently upgraded from 20.04 to 21.10 and everything else seems to be working OK.

Well, any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

`apt update` produces the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                           
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                              
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [115 kB]                                                
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                     
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [20,3 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]   
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.616 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [25,7 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [6.860 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35,5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [5.952 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [16,4 kB]
Fetched 441 kB in 2s (196 kB/s)              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
6 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

The upgradable packages are related to Thunderbird, so I think they’re not relevant to the `libczmq` installation.

Comment: Let's look at libsodium23. Your system is complaining that there are two versions: A=1.0.18-1build1 and B=1.0.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. A is the one from the Ubuntu repositories. B is from some non-Ubuntu source. libsodium23 is compatible with A, incompatible with B. However, B has the higher version string, so apt thinks that you want B installed. Delete B and install A.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a billion.